# Keyboard and trackpad launching too long after opening a lid

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, sleep-wake, trackpad

I own a MacBook Pro (late 2019, 13 inch, 10.15.5).

I have an issue that when I open a lid  sometimes takes too long up to 10 seconds to launch a keyboard and when the backlight turns on it is a sign that it is ready.

It can even tell that it doesn't see a keyboard and tries to connect to a wireless keyboard and mouse.

Maybe somebody had this issue too and can help. Thank you!